# Apply easing function to animation behind code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I managed to build my storyboard behind code. I don't know how to add easing functions though. I am looking for something like:

```
DoubleAnimation FadelnTBAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
FadelnTBAnimation.To = 0;
FadelnTBAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
FadelnTBAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
FadelnTBAnimation.EasingFunction = EasingMode.EaseInOut; // this line gives an error
```

How could I apply easing functions with c#?

The reason why I find useful to build the storyboard with code Is because I am applying the same animation to several objects and sometimes it does not work when I bind the target property in XAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an instance of IEasingFunction (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.ieasingfunction.aspx). There is a list of implementation classes at the bottom of that documentation entry, the most common of which is probably CubicEase or QuadraticEase.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between the easing-function and the easing-mode.

Here is a short example for Win-8 (not WPF):

```
SineEase easingFunction = new SineEase();
easingFunction.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;
animation.EasingFunction = easingFunction;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to add the easing function in your case would be to just add it to the double animation.

```
FadelnTBAnimation.EasingFunction = new QuarticEase(); // for example
```